# Flask / telebot: Bot can't receive POST and work at the same time

Tags: python, flask, telegram

everyone. I need telebot to receive POST and answer. I decided to use Flask.
I have code:

```
import telebot
from flask import Flask, request
bot = telebot.TeleBot('dddd')
print("1")


app = Flask(__name__)
print("2")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    print("5")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.chat.username)

print("3")


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    dt = request.args.to_dict(flat=False)
    print("6")
    for i in dt["chatIds"]:
        print(i)
        bot.send_message(i, "tema loh")

    return "0"

print("4")

bot.polling()
```

When I launch Flask I see:

```
F:\Desktop\backend\bot_14_11>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "bot.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

Bot is working, but I can't send POST to my localhost.
I press ctrl+c and see:

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Then I can send POST, but bot is not responding on "start" command

I need them to work together

Comment: Run the `bot` & `app` on 2 different threads

Comment: could you please name a library or give a hint?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bot.polling()` is a blocking call and runs in its own loop. Running a Flask app, similarly, blocks forever. Running one will prevent the other from running. Hence, you cannot run these two together like this.

Here's what's happening in your code and why you see the behavior your see:

When you start by running `flask run` Flask will attempt to import the `app` object from your module. However, the import will never finish because `bot.polling()` is blocking forever. Then, if you press `ctrl+c`, the bot will stop running, allowing Flask to import and run your Flask app. As you observed, the bot will not run with Flask concurrently.

You might be able to get away with running your bot in a separate thread, but you have to be careful about your use of threads.

```py
import threading
...  # all your code as-is except for the last `bot.polling` line...

t = threading.Thread(target=bot.polling, daemon=True)
t.start()  # start the bot in a thread instead
```

However, threading is its own topic in which you should be intimately familiar before trying this. You should also consider whether or not the libraries/code you're using are thread-safe.

Instead, to avoid complications that threading may add, I would recommend splitting your bot and your Flask app into separately running applications. Use some sort of other mechanism to communicate between them, if necessary. I.E. run a separate python processes for each application.